How to conduct Aws deep racer custom events?
How to conduct Aws deep racer custom events. What are the necessary procedures should be followed to set up a aws deep racer event? is it possible to conduct aws deep racer event in educational institution. i want to know about how aws events are conducted, resources and pricing.?
I want to know about how Aws deepracer events are conducted?
